# Comparing same column in two tables, returning unique values

Tags: sql

I am new to this site and have a little knowledge of SQL. I am trying to build a query in our automation studio (email platform). I would like to compare two similar columns in different tables and return only unique values. So a little background, I have a list that I want to remove all who have previously unsubscribed.

I have already built part of the query where it is returning distinct email addresses that have traveled within a specific time frame from table1. I want to know if I am able to compare table1 to another i.e. table2 and return only those that are unique and not found on table2. This is what I have right now but need to add a command to compare the two tables and return unique values.

```
select distinct EmailAddress<br>
from ENT.table1<br>
where (Outbound_Dept_Date between '20190301 00:01:00' and '20200229 23:59:00')
```

I tried to search through a few posts but couldn't find anything that matched what I need, so if there is one, please share if it relates to what I am looking for. Let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery

```
select distinct EmailAddress
from ENT.table1
where (Outbound_Dept_Date between '20190301 00:01:00' and '20200229 23:59:00')
and EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress 
                         from ENT.table2
                         where (Outbound_Dept_Date between '20190301 00:01:00' and '20200229 23:59:00'))
```

The second where condition selects all email addresses that are not table2

Comment: Thank you @mattyx17 this helped! I had to make a couple adjustments such as the Outbound_Dept_Date doesn't exist in table2. But I got it to work with the results I was looking for!